# I wrote a simple time measurement library in C++

Tags: c++, library, benchmarking

**welcome everybody**

I wrote a simple code to measure time easily

### Features

- **Easy**  include and just call `timeit()`
- **Fast**  It just calculates the average time in the loop
- **Light** No lots of code, just one function is written
- **CrossPlatform** It doesn't using any third party libraries, so it should work anywhere

### Syntax

```cpp
timeit(name, count, function, args).unit();
```

### Example

```cpp
#include "timeit.hpp"

void func(int a, int b){ /* do something */ }

timeit("test1", 1000, func, 5, 5).microseconds();
```

*result*

```
[TIMEIT] [test1]: 500192[µs]
```

### Units

- **seconds**
- **milliseconds**
- **microseconds**

---

### Source Code

```cpp
/**
 * @file    timeit.hpp
 * @brief   A simple measure time way
 * @version 0.1
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2022 Maysara Elshewehy (xeerx.com) (maysara.elshewehy@gmail.com)
 *
 * Distributed under the MIT License (MIT) 
*/

#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>

// DON'T USE IT, IT JUST HELPER FOR THE FUNCTION timeit()
class __timeit
{
    private:
    // name of test
    std::string name;

    // average result between all test results
    size_t result = 0;

    // storing test results
    std::vector<size_t> results;

    public:

    // constructor: init name
    __timeit(std::string n) : name{n} {}

    // print result in seconds
    void seconds() { std::cout << name << result / 1000 / 1000 << "[" << "s" << "]" << std::endl; }
    // print result in milliseconds
    void milliseconds() { std::cout << name  << result / 1000 << "[" << "ms" << "]" << std::endl; }
    // print result in microseconds
    void microseconds() { std::cout << name  << result << "[" << "µs" << "]" << std::endl; }

    // get average result between all test results and set `result`
    void get()          { result = std::reduce(results.begin(), results.end()) / results.size(); }
    // push test `result` to `results`
    void set(size_t val){ results.push_back(val); }
};

// USE IT WITH ANY TYPE OF FUNCTIONS AND ANY NUMBER/TYPE OF PARAMETERS
template <class F, typename ...A>
__timeit timeit(std::string name, int count, F func, A&& ...args)
{
    // create `__timeit` class and set name
    __timeit clss("[TIMEIT] [" + name + "]: ");

    // loop
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // get time at beginning
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        // execute function
        func(std::forward<A>(args)...);

        // get time at finishing
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        // call `set()` function to push result to results vector
        clss.set(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count());
    }

    // now call `get()` function to get average result between all test results and set `result`
    clss.get();

    // return to class object, so we can call units functions like: timeit(...).second(); easy right? :]
    return clss;
}
```

---

### Questions

- **Is there a better way?**
- **Are there errors?**
- **Any tips?**

---

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/xeerx/timeit/tree/9ac9ed67194e421f19a214044fb4f2b2dc5fec97)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Don't do any time conversions yourself

By storing the elapsed time in microseconds, and doing integer divisions when asking for the elapsed time in seconds, you lose precision. Also, what if you want the time in nanoseconds or minutes? The best you can do is actually not do time conversions at all. Just keep durations stored as [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), and return that to the user, and they can cast it to whatever type they want themselves.

## Don't store intermediate results longer than necessary

There is no need to have a class `__timeit` with a member variable `results` where intermediate results are stored in indefinitely. You only need this vector inside `timeit()` itself. Or even better, don't store them at all if you just need the sum:

```
template <class F, typename ...A>
auto timeit(int count, F func, A&& ...args)
{
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    clock::duration total_duration = {};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        auto begin = clock::now();
        func(std::forward<A>(args)...);
        auto end = clock::now();

        total_duration += end - begin;
    }

    return total_duration / count;
}
```

## Don't use double underscores

[Some uses of underscores in names are reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). In particular, double underscores are always reserved, and you should not use them yourself.

## Warm-up, autoscaling, errors

Your way of measuring the time a function takes is unfortunately a bit naive. The first time a function is called it might take a very different time to run than a subsequent time it is called, because of caches, branch predictors and memory not having been "warmed up" to the function you are calling. It sometimes takes a surprisingly large number of calls before everything has settled. If you are going to call a function a million times, doing a hundred thousand calls to warm up everything before is a small price to pay.

It's hard to know up front how long a function will take, and humans are usually not very patient. So it would be nice if autoscaling was implemented, so it will run for a fixed amount of time (say, a few seconds by default).

The individual time measurements will contain errors. This is because computers are typically non-deterministic, having to deal with interrupts, frequency scaling, and other things that will influence how fast things are running. The function you are calling itself might be non-deterministic. If you are going to record individual time measurements, consider doing some statistics on them. For example, either the minimum time or the median time or is probably more relevant than the average. You might also want to make the standard deviation available to the user, and maybe the maximum and 95th percentile values as well.

Finally, measuring time costs time itself. The cost of one call to `clock::now()` will be included in each time measurement. Ideally, you want to subtract that. A good way to do this would be to also measure the time it takes calling a no-op function, and subtract that time from your results.

## Comparison with Python's `timeit` module

Python's `timeit` module not only has the `timeit()` function, but also a `repeat()` function and a `Timer` class. While not all the functionality in the `timeit` module is useful for C++, if you want to provide something that is familiar to a Python user, then it might be nice to implement `Timer` and `repeat()` at least.

Also note that Python's `timeit()` returns the total time for all iterations of the function, not just the average time for a single function call.

Comment: Thank you, I will follow your advice and update the code

Comment: Note, I don't use Python so I didn't know there was a library with the same name :D
I don't want it to take more than one line
So the value must be converted through class functions
like: timeit(...).unit(); just it

Comment: On your advice, I upgraded it to the third version, and I'm waiting for your opinion

Comment: @xeerx It's great that you want to improve your code, but once someone has answered a question, you should not modify the question anymore. See [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). You can however create a new question here on Code Review with your revised code, and then we can review that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know it was wrong, thank you